# "checkpointer process" is consuming more memory in Postgres. How to control it?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

We have a database cluster as "db1_data". Under this cluster we have two databases. one is db1 and other is qovr. I surprised to see as "checkpointer process" is consuming 8.73GB of memory(RSS value as 9158892). Why "checkpointer process" is consuming this much amount of memory and how to limit the usage of the "checkpointer process" memory.

[image: ps command output]

Comment: You are probably only seeing the shared memory from `shared_buffers`. Don't worry. This memory is displayed for many PostgreSQL processes, although it exists only once.

Comment: If you see the log , you can find few more postgres processors/connections are consuming more than 1gb of memory.

Comment: Interesting. How do you see that in the log?

Comment: `ps` will include the shared memory allocated by the parent process. As the parent postgres process allocated the shared memory for `shared_buffers` it is expected that every child process listed by ps gives the expression that it uses that much memory.

Answer (score -1):

I have a similar situation. I have two processes eating out 16GB of RAM each (postgres: checkpointer process AND postgres: writer process). I looked at the output of the command

```
pmap -p PID_OF_PROCESS
```

and found that the largest memory is occupied by the "deleted" /dev/zero.

Why did it happen? I did not find a solution to free memory. This is a test environment, so I just rebooted PG.